# Чтение из файла по одному числу, c#

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть файл на миллион чисел, разделенных пробелом (одной строкой). Можно ли как-то читать числа по одному? Потому что чтение строки целиком очень нагружает память.
Пробовал через StreamReader.Read, но он считывает посимвольно. Конечно, можно читать символы пока не встречу пробел и складывать из них числа, но это кажется не очень красивым вариантом, может есть методы специально для такого?
Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Почему читать по символьно вам не нравится? По мне так годны вариант. Если вы беспокоитесь о производительности, то оберните поток в BufferedStream, который будет читать файл блоками, а вы посимвольно будете читать уде из буфера в памяти

Comment: Можно посмотреть исходный код [ReadLine](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,a4ada5f765646068,references) и написать метод расширения под свои нужды

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишем нехитрую функцию для чтения из потока

```
public IEnumerable<int> ReadNumbers(Stream st)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(st))
    {
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            char digit = (char)sr.Read();
            if (!char.IsDigit(digit))
            {
                if (buffer.Length == 0) continue;
                int ret = Int32.Parse(buffer.ToString());
                buffer.Clear();
                yield return  ret;
            }
            else {
                buffer.Append(digit);
            }
        }

        if (buffer.Length != 0)
        {
            int ret = Int32.Parse(buffer.ToString());
            buffer.Clear();
            yield return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы читать файл побайтово

```
foreach(var n in ReadNumbers(File.OpenRead(@"D:\temp\sample.txt")))
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Чтобы читать файл с буфером в мегабайт

```
foreach (var n in 
           ReadNumbers(
              new BufferedStream(
                   File.OpenRead(@"D:\temp\sample.txt"), 
                   1024 * 1024)))
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Comment: Да, вот что-то такое я и имел ввиду, надеялся есть в стандартных библиотеках) Спасибо большое!

Comment: @SaliceSmove пожалуйста