# Как сортировать строки в большом(2Гб) файле?

Tags: c#, сортировка

Строки разной длины и из разных символов, т.е. вариант с сортировкой подсчетом, не катит. 
Сделал внешнюю сортировку слиянием. Разбиваю файл на куски по 100Мб, сортирую каждый, выполняю слияние. 
Все это занимает у меня около 10 минут. 
Хотя рядом лежит чужой софт, который за 6 минут сортирует тот же объем и выполняет удаление дублей из него.

Прикладываю свой код.

```
public static class Sorting
{
    public static void ExternalMergeSort(string originalFile, string newFile)
    {
        //Разбить файл на части по 100 Мб
        string dir = SplitFile(originalFile);
        //Отсортировать каждую часть

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            InternalSort(file);

        //Многопоточный вариант - не хватает памяти
        //List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        //foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        //{
        //    Task t = new Task(() => InternalSort(file));
        //    tasks.Add(t);
        //    t.Start();
        //}
        //Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        //Объединить части
        MergeFilesInDirectory(dir);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Разбитие файла на куски укaзанного размера
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalFile">Файл для разбития</param>
    /// <param name="maxFileSize">Максимальный размер части файла. Default = 100Mb</param>
    /// <returns>Путь к папке с частями файла</returns>
    private static string SplitFile(string originalFile, double maxFileSize= 1e+8)
    {
        TimeWatcher.Start("SplitFile");

        var lines = File.ReadLines(originalFile);

        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(originalFile);
        string extDir = dir + "/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile);
        if (!Directory.Exists(extDir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(extDir);

        string partPath = extDir + "/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(originalFile);

        var outputFile = new StreamWriter( File.OpenWrite(partPath));
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(line);
            if (outputFile.BaseStream.Position >= maxFileSize)
            {
                outputFile.Close();
                partPath = extDir + "/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(originalFile);
                outputFile = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(partPath));
            }
        }

        TimeWatcher.Show("SplitFile", true);
        return extDir;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Внутренняя сортировка файла
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalFile">Сортируемый файл</param>
    public static void InternalSort(string originalFile)
    {
        TimeWatcher.Start("InternalSort");

        List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines(originalFile).ToList();
        list.Sort();
        File.WriteAllLines(originalFile, list);

        TimeWatcher.Show("InternalSort", true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Слияние файлов в указанной директории
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dir">директория с файлами</param>
    private static void MergeFilesInDirectory(string dir)
    {
        TimeWatcher.Start("MergeFilesInDirectory");

        // Открываем все файлы разом и формируем слой чтения
        List<StreamReader> readers = new List<StreamReader>();
        List<string> layer = new List<string>(readers.Count);
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file));
            readers.Add(reader);
            layer.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }

        //Создаем файл результата
        var writter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(dir + "/Result.txt"));

        int Id = 0;
        while(layer.FirstOrDefault(x=>x!=null) != null)
        {
            string min = layer.Min();
            Id = layer.IndexOf(min);
            layer[Id] = readers[Id].ReadLine();
            writter.WriteLine(min);
        }

        writter.Close();
        foreach (var reader in readers)
            reader.Close();

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) != "Result")
                File.Delete(file);
        }
        TimeWatcher.Show("MergeFilesInDirectory", true);
    }
}
```

Нашел возможность увеличить максимальный размер объекта(в .NET ограничение 2Гб).
Благодаря этому можно спокойно прочитать весь файл в память, а уже там отрывать куски. Чтение 2 Гб(с SSD в DDR3) заняло 0.7 секунд.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>  
..
```

Подробности тут: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/8d5880fe-108e-47d2-bbd7-4669e0aec1ec/-2-?forum=programminglanguageru

Comment: 1) Читайте с буфером 2) Пишите с буфером 3) Сортируйте за логарифм

Comment: А по подробнее?)

Comment: ну, как минимум, я вижу, что вы считываете строки по одной за раз. Пишете тоже по 1 стоке за раз. Но чтобы эффективно читать с жесткого диска и писать, вам надо уменьшить количество считываний / записей. Вы этого можете добиться при помощи буфера в памяти. Я уже писал про это: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848376/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/862074/179763), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858604/179763), ну, или вот у меня [был вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768072/179763), где я генерировал 16 гигов и сортировал их за 25 минут

Comment: @tym32167, подправил. Скорость разбития файла выросла в 3 раза(с 30 секунд до 10). Уже спасибо!
Однако основное время отбирает сортировка. Ваш вопрос почитал, но чет так и не понял, куда рыть. Ткните пальцем пожалуйста)

Comment: В методе `SplitFile` вы читаете 100 Мб и записываете в новый файл. Потом в методе `InternalSort` повторно читаете эти же данные. Измените алгоритм: читайте из большого файла 100 Мб в список, сразу сортируйте его и записывайте. Потом останется лишь смержить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, сортировка одного файла(с чтением) занимает 26 секунд. Ваш вариант позволит выиграть максимум пару секунд.

Comment: Насколько я понял, у вас сортировка 100 мб файла забирает большую часть времени. Думаю, что если вы не знаете специфики строк на входе (короткие строки или длинные, много ли дубликатов, есть ли конечный алфавит в строках этих), то ничего лучше, чем то, что вы используете в голову не приходит. Можно разве что на объединении файлов несколько секунд выиграть, но это капля в море.

Comment: Я вообщем то сделал. Удаление строк из файла 1Гб, содержащихся в файле 100мб за 1.5 минуты.

Comment: Это в двое быстрее, аналогичного софта.

Comment: Малый файл читаем в память целиком как массив байт. Разбиваем массив на куски по разделителю 0x0A(разделитель включаем в строку).

Comment: Хороший вопрос для рубрики "масштабируй это!" - когда всё начинается с простого вопроса типа "как отсортировать набор строк, прочитанный из файла?" - а потом переходим к рассмотрению крайних случаев, таких, как у вас - очень большой файл. Но строчка gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" в конфигурации - прямо спасение!

Comment: @S.H. мне больше всего нравится формулировка по типу "very large objects")

Comment: @S.H., а нафига там very large objects? По идее нужен массив строк - вряд ли строка больше 2\*\*28 символов, и вряд ли в файле больше 2\*\*30 строк.

Answer (score 1):

Для ускорения работы с файлом, используйьте mmap — "POSIX-совместимый системный вызов Unix, позволяющий выполнить отображение файла или устройства на память."

Answer (score 0):

Малый файл читаем в память целиком как массив байт. Разбиваем массив на куски по разделителю 0x0A(разделитель включаем в строку). Сортируем получившийся массив кусков( Потребуется написать свой Comparer). Затем открываем BufferedStream на чтение большого файла и еще один такой же стрим на запись в выходной файл. Тут я для удобства использова StreamReader. Читаем строку. Получаем байты строки в unicode. И выполняем бинарный поиск этого массива байт строки в нашем отсортированном массиве кусков малого файла. Если не нашли - записываем в выходной файл.
Так же можно дополнительно сохранять отсортированный массив в тот же файл, из которого его получили и каким то образом запоминать, что файл уже отсортирован и при следуещем его использовании не сортировать. 
Важно. Сборка должна выполняться под x64. Размер файла который читается целиком - не должен быть больше 2ГБ. Иначе функция File.ReadAllBytes выдаст исключение.